# Where can I found logs for WCPP.exe?

Tags: c#, windows, logging, printing, neodynamic

Where can I found logs to Windows Print Client by Neodynamic? There is nothing in EventViewer, no log files in instalation dir, no configuration.

I try to implement pringing by them client, I do everything like they in sample project, by printing client give me error. I have somewehe error, but I can not localize it.

[image]

Comment: No clue if this is what you're looking for, but it seems about right [WCPP Diagnostics](http://wcpp-diagnostics.software.informer.com/)

Comment: I think it is not it. Author of WCPP is Xerox, I use Neodynamic's library

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To reslove this problem you have to

- Create your own ashx handler, which contains printing code
- Get away handler form auth by entry in web.config
- Now it should works.

There is more info [WebClientPrint](http://www.neodynamic.com/articles/How-to-use-WebClientPrint-with-ASP-NET-Authentication-enabled/)
Thanks for Neodynamic support team for this link

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @bwest: Kinda did, really. Links to what appears to be an external tool along with minimal additional instruction on how to use it.

Comment: You think that if the link dies, the answer is still useful?

Comment: @bwest: I reedit my answer, I hope now it is moew useful